# Can reviewers and authors of a submitted journal paper (for peer-review), be from the same country?

Tags: journals, paper-submission

Does the nationality of the authors has to do with the chosen reviewers? What I mean is this: if two authors submit a journal paper, and their nationality is from country "A", can the reviewers be also from country "A" or the editor does not choose reviewers from country "A" and chooses reviewers from country "B"?

Comment: I ask also for nationality, which is not covered to the proposed questions...Can you reopen my question, please?

Comment: Also see [Under what circumstances is there a conflict of interest for a researcher to be a reviewer of a submitted academic paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/72010/17254). I've never heard any publication venue even suggest that merely being from the same country as (some of the) authors would constitute a conflict of interest, though researchers in countries like Luxembourg might be quite restricted.

Comment: @just_learning I think that's covered by the new duplicate that Anyon commented.

Comment: Woudn't be good to have various and more opinions? I mean what's the point of asking a question and having only one opinion?  A closed question prevents people from submitting their opinion....